# Linq to Entities - JOIN a list with an entity set

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I am able to join a list (collection) with an entity set using listname.Join() method.

For example,

```
var query = listName.Join(repository.GetQuery<MyCustomType>(),
 list => list.CustomTypeId,
 customType => customType.id,
 (list, customType) => list);
```

This is working fine, but it returns only rows related to list collection in the entity. I also want instance of "MyCustomType" in resultset. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = listName.Join(repository.GetQuery<MyCustomType>(),
 list => list.CustomTypeId,
 customType => customType.id,
 (list, customType) => new { l = list, c = customType } );
```

Comment: This will load all the entities from DB into memmory!

Comment: @downvoter That is not relevant to the question. The OP simply asked how to include the data from both sides of the join. The underlying query is the same as how the OP posted. Rather than downvoting my post, you would be better to post an alternative answer targeting that issue and the original issue in question.